# How can I merge two arrays into one

Tags: php

I've looked on this site and have found a few examples of merging arrays but to be honest, I'm not sure which one is right for me.

I am having a difficult time trying to merge these arrays. I've tried array_combine and array_merge but I am not having any luck.

What I need is a single array with the output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [UnitNo] => 91
            [Name] => Receiving
            [ActivityNo] =>
            [Active] => 2
            [CallNo] =>
            [CallStatusNo] =>
            [Assigned] =>
            [UnitId] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [UnitNo] => 83
            [Name] => Shipping
            [ActivityNo] =>
            [Active] =>
            [CallNo] =>
            [CallStatusNo] =>
            [Assigned] =>
            [UnitId] => 1
        )
)
```

These are the two arrays that I need to merge together based on the `UnitId` that should form a complete array like the one above. I just don't know how to do this. If someone could direct me a bit, I would be grateful.

```
// Array #1
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [UnitId] => 2
            [UnitNo] => 91
            [Name] => Receiving
            [Active] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [UnitId] => 1
            [UnitNo] => 83
            [Name] => Shipping
            [Active] => 4
        )
)
// Array #2

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [UnitId] => 2
            [ActivityNo] => 1
            [CallNo] => 1
            [CallStatusNo] => 1
            [Assigned] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [UnitId] => 1
            [ActivityNo] => 11
            [CallNo] => 2
            [CallStatusNo] => 1
            [Assigned] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: You should look the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: @demonofnight, thanks. If array_merge will work for me then I'll look into that function more. I just wanted to be sure that it will do what I need it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a case where you can just use a php function and call it good - you will have to do some custom logic of your own.

This would work, but only if both `$array1` and `$array2` have the same items at each index.

```
$array1;
$array2;
$mergedArray;

for ($i=0; $i++; $i < count($array1) - 1) {
    //first add all the values from array1
    $mergedArray[$i] = $array1[$i];

    foreach($array2[$i] as $array2Key=>$array2Value){
        //now check for missing key/values that are in array2 but not in array1
        if (array_key_exists($array2Key, $array1[$i]) == false) {
            // the key does not exist in array1, so add it to mergedArray
            $mergedArray[$i][$array2Key] = $array2Value;
        }
    }
}
```

It would be safer if your arrays were associative arrays, indexed by a unique value.